# How to Use AspNet.Identity core in My Sql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I am developing one application using **asp dot net core 2** using **MySql database**.Please help me How can i use **Asp Net Identity** in **MySqlDatabase**.

Comment: Though this is a very late comment, this video will walk you through how to make it work on asp net core 3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4I0DUw6C84

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had to do this for a client. And I did in an application with ASP.NET Core 1.0, but for curiosity I also tried for an application in .NET Core 2.0.

What I did was first install the Entity Framework MySQL package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/ using package manager console.

After that I changed in the *startup.cs*, in the method *ConfigureServices*, the option *UseSqlServer* to *UseMySql*, like the image below.

[image]

In my appsettings.json I have the MySQL connection named IdentityConnection like this:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "IdentityConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=identitycoredb;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;"
    },
```

To create the identity tables I executed the migration command in package manager console:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database -Verbose
```

[image]

Comment: this works well with .Net Core 2.0 & Pomelo 2.0.1 versions. But if you move to Core 2.1 then you will see pomelo hasn't made yet 2.1.0 so there is a bug which blocks db migrations.

Comment: Thanks for saying that @MehmetKurtipek. I didn't know about it.

Comment: @MehmetKurtipek They have fixed the bug in the latest pre-release version (v2.1.0-rc1-final).

Comment: @AndyFurniss thanks for the info, I have noticed that today!

Comment: running this in .Net Core 2.2, with newly created project fails, any suggestions?

Comment: can you plz tell me how to get system stored procedure in MYSQL?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
At this point, .Net Core 2.0 doesn't support Identity with MySql, in a near future it may be supported again.

__

You need to plug Entity Framework with MySQL with Pomelo's connection and Identity should work. Check this out -> https://damienbod.com/2016/08/26/asp-net-core-1-0-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-core/

Comment: It will create all the Migrations ie( it will create all tables like AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, etc..) And Is this Lib support for Core 2.0

Comment: You're right. I did it with 1.3 and it works. But at this point 2.0 doesn't have support. I'm sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @Bellash looks it's working with MySql since 2.0.5. Check this blog post. https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/03/20/csharp-dotnet-core-identity-mysql/

Comment: @Claudio : sir can you tell me how to use system stored procedure of identity server in mysql database?

Answer (score 2):

You Can create an Identity Database along with your MySQL Database 
and use the Identity database for your authorization

This is how I do it.

```
   //MySQL Database 
     services.AddDbContext<EFDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer("Server = ; Database =MySQL  ; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true"));
//Identity Database               
     services.AddDbContext<EFIdentityDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer("Server = ; Database = Identity; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true"));
```

This should work fine along with your MySQL DB

```
public class EFIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public EFIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<EFIdentityDbContext> options )
        :base (options)
    {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this answer but, this developer has put the whole solution nicely, in this repository.

https://github.com/jasonsturges/mysql-dotnet-core

Putting the relevant code blocks here.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.Id).HasMaxLength(127));
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.ConcurrencyStamp).HasColumnType("varchar(256)"));

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(127);
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.RoleId).HasMaxLength(127);
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.Name).HasMaxLength(127);
    });
}
```

This is tested by me on a project i was working on at the time of posting this answer.

Comment: essentially, it adds the items that the error claims as far as the my sql db is concerned.