# HttpContext.SignInAsync does not work when you consume it through .razor page

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, blazor

I implement ASP.NET Core cookie Authentication In blazor server side.
I write simple API Controller with Login endpoint.

When I post to API via postman everything works fine and I become identified and Authorized.

When I post via HttpClient: `_http.PostJsonAsync<bool>("api/auth/Login", credentials);`

I hit the API endpoint and its run to till end without error but the Authentication State don't change and no cookie is created.

```
var res = await _http.PostJsonAsync<bool>("api/v1/Auth/Login", credentials);
```

api:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<bool> Login()
{
  const string Issuer = "mydomain.com";
  var claims = new List<Claim>
  {
    new Claim("ID", dataTable.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer),
    new Claim("FullName", dataTable.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer),
    new Claim("CompanyName", dataTable.Rows[0]["CompanyName"].ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer),
    new Claim("Email", dataTable.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer),
  };

  var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "User");
  var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

  await HttpContext.SignInAsync
  (
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    userPrincipal,
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
      ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
      IsPersistent = false,
      AllowRefresh = false
    }
  );

  return true;

}
```

Comment: Why use HttpClient when your app is executed on the server. Making http request when using server-side Blazor is possible, but rather unnecessary. I believe the issue is with the configuration of the HttpClient service, but I cannot detect the problem as your code is missing some parts...

Comment: this is because when using HttpContext Inside blazor page you get error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.'

Comment: Which is  a clue to why login doesn't work: you're not on HTTP anymore.

Comment: The call is not done in http even though I use HttpClient?

Comment: That call is http(s) alright, but your main connection is  SignalR. The cookie is not processed. Maybe it works when you navigate to a non-blazor page and back again.

Comment: But basically, use the built-in authentication (that adds the Identity Razor Pages to your project).

Comment: This means that if I refresh the page or go to another page as you said it will work

But in practice it is not and the cookie is not created at all

Because it is signalR I update my current identity but it also does not help.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using Identity Razor Pages with EF because the organization is working with MYSQL and for now it is not yet supported

Comment: So it's really an X/Y question:  How to do Identity with MySql? It does seem possible: [1](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/03/20/csharp-dotnet-core-identity-mysql/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298605/how-to-use-aspnet-identity-core-in-my-sql-database)

Comment: Also, note that "... go to another page" is not enough, it needs to be a non-Blazor (non SignalR) page.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solution for your problem:

1. Place a call to the login method in a page that is loading;that is,in the event OnInitAsync, but this is not useful because you probably want it to execute when a button is clicked...
2. This is the solution you are looking for: Using A Redirect Login Page. This is from the referenced link below:

   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
       CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
       new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
       authProperties);

Can only be set if we start a new http request. This is achieved by redirecting the user to the page that sets the user.

See full article: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4316/A-Demonstration-of-Simple-Server-side-Blazor-Cookie-Authentication.aspx

Good luck...

Comment: There is a way to know whether the user is still authorized at the time of his activity in signalR Blazor Page?

Comment: Redirecting to a login.cshtml works, but poorly. When I'm redirected back to Blazor the entire SPA reloads (visibly, I get a white screen for a moment). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689443/server-side-blazor-page-post-to-razor-page-http-error-400. Is there any other way?

Comment: Also, as Raphael pointed out in the article's comments:  href="/login?paramUsername=@encode(@Username)&paramPassword=@encode(@Password)" This means the password might be CACHED IN PLAINTEXT by the browser, which is insecure. To my understanding, calls to a Razor Page are not hidden behind SignalR.