# Server-side Blazor page post to Razor page http error 400

Tags: razor-pages, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to post my username and password from a Blazor page (.razor) to a Razor Page(.cshtml) but I get http error 400 all the time.

**LoginControl.razor**

```
<form method="post" action="login">
        <input type="text"
               name="username"
               @bind="@Username"
               placeholder="User Name" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="password"
               name="password"
               placeholder="Password"
               @bind="@Password" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary">Loggin</button>
    </form>
```

**Login.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromServices] IUserProvider provider, string username, string password)
    {
Login stuff
}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted a Blazor component and a Razor code-behind file. Where is the link up?

Comment: I thought that the /login in the action on the Blazor component will redirect and post to the login page.

Comment: There are likely to be a number of fields in your class that need to be initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad request (400) means that the server cannot understand you

The method="post" is not applicable in Blazor or any other SPA frameworks. In Blazor there is special code that prevent a post back. Of course you can force a postback, which means that your Blazor page expires, and if you try to return to it, it is rerendered, and all your previous state is lost.

What you're trying to do here is to get the user's credentials in a Blazor component, and then try to post the data to a Razor Page Model for validation. You can't do that, and you should not do that. You should redirect your user to a login page in which he enters his credentials and those credentials should be validated against some sort of store, say SqlServer database, and then returns to the Blazor app. Remember, the redirection to a Razor Page means that your Blazor app has expired. Once again you do not post the user's credentials to the Login Razor Page. The user should enter his his credentials on Login.cshtml

I'd suggest you to use the Blazor built-in system to enable authentication and authorization. This system uses the Identity Ui (Razor Pages) to authenticate the user. It does exactly what you're trying to do. [See here...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). Also, use the Forms Components provided by Blazor, such as EditForm, InutText, etc.

Comment: But in this case I am redirected to a Razor page (for login) so it should work. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Isn't that for client-side Blazor? It didn't work when I tried it previously. This did work: http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4316/A-Demonstration-of-Simple-Server-side-Blazor-Cookie-Authentication.aspx But I want to change it to use post instead of get.

Comment: I've added a clarification to my answer in response to your last comment.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand how it works and I got it working.

Comment: I am converting the Identity Razor Page templates to Blazor.  Going from Login.razor to ExternalLogin.razor via POST fails.  I guess I need to combine the two pages.