# OnPostAsync not called

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I try to implement a E-Mail sender in my Blazor server-side app. I'm following this example:

https://kenhaggerty.com/articles/article/aspnet-core-22-smtp-emailsender-implementation

I have the view **Home.cshtml**

```
@page "/Home"
@model UserManagement.HomeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";

}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <label class="alert alert-success">@Model.EmailStatusMessage</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Email Test</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the **Home.cshtml.cs**

```
 public class HomeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public HomeModel(IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        public string EmailStatusMessage { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [BindProperty]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }

            var email = Email;

            var subject = "Email Test";

            var message = "This is a test message.";

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email, subject, message);

            EmailStatusMessage = "Send test email was successful.";


        }
    }
}
```

When I hit the button, I receive a 400 error and the debugger never stops at my breakpoint which I have set in the OnPostAsync method. I'm a little confused why that never happens.

Can you solve this mystery?

Comment: what is your project structure?How does it related to blazor?Is there any errors?

Answer (score 5):

You have to add "_ViewImports.cshtml" file with the following "usings"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Then add to this file the namespaces you'll be using on thosse pages

Comment: Thanks! Missing tag helpers was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I think I stumbled across another post here where a similar issue was discussed. The post of enet explains it:

[Server-side Blazor page post to Razor page http error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689443/server-side-blazor-page-post-to-razor-page-http-error-400)

I quote:

> The method="post" is not applicable in Blazor or any other SPA
>   frameworks. In Blazor there is special code that prevent a post back.
>   Of course you can force a postback, which means that your Blazor page
>   expires, and if you try to return to it, it is rerendered, and all
>   your previous state is lost.
>
> What you're trying to do here is to get the user's credentials in a
>   Blazor component, and then try to post the data to a Razor Page Model
>   for validation. You can't do that, and you should not do that. You
>   should redirect your user to a login page in which he enters his
>   credentials and those credentials should be validated against some
>   sort of store, say SqlServer database, and then returns to the Blazor
>   app. Remember, the redirection to a Razor Page means that your Blazor
>   app has expired. One again you do not post the user's credentials to
>   the Login Razor Page. The user should enter his his credentials on
>   Login.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

please use as-page-handler in your form tag `<form asp-page-handler="Data" method="post">`
as well as use a name same in your handler
`public async Task OnPostDataAsync() { //your code here }`