# What is the app.config equivalent for .NET Core/5.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, mysql-connector, .net-5

I am trying to port code from a .NET Framework project to .NET Core/5.0, specifically my problem here is getting my [custom MySQL authentication plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-authentication-user-plugin.html) working.

For .NET Framework, instructing the application to use the custom plugin requires this adding to the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration,
MySql.Data"/>
  </configSections>
  <MySQL>
    <AuthenticationPlugins>
      <add name="mysql_native_password"
type="AuthPluginTest.MySqlNativePasswordPlugin2, AuthPluginTest"></add>
    </AuthenticationPlugins>  
  </MySQL>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup></configuration>
```

However, I am now using Entity Framework and .NET 5.0, which do not use app.config files. How can I apply the configuration in this context?

**Edit**:
To clarify, I do have the MySQL database working, but need to use my own auth plugin as the native method keeps the connection string in memory. The custom auth plugin was the solution after it was raised as an issue in a PEN test.

Comment: Check [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You don't need a custom plugin any more, you can add multiple different configuration sources. There are several built-in providers and creating a new one is very easy. [The custom provider example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-configuration-provider) in the docs loads settings from a database.

Comment: For *authentication* though, what you need to configure is the [ASP.NET Core Identity middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). It can already talk to databases through EF Core so all you really need to do is replace `UseSqlServer` with `UseMySql` as [this probably duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298605/how-to-use-aspnet-identity-core-in-my-sql-database) question shows

Comment: You can create a new web app with the `Individual User Accounts` to save accounts in a database. The out-of-the-box options are SQLite for testing or SQL Server. The only thing that needs changing to target MySQL is the EF Core provider

Comment: Thanks for the comments - just to clarify, I do have the MySQL database working, but need to use my own auth plugin as the native one keeps a copy of the connection string in memory. The custom plugin was the solution after it was raised in a PEN test

Comment: In that case you need a different ADO.NET provider, not plugin. Because it's ADO.NET that uses the connection string. `was the solution after it was raised in a PEN test` and how is this going to prevent the string from staying in memory until it's garbage-collected?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Using a custom plugin allowed the 'GetPassword' method to be overridden with my own implementation, which avoided having to include the password in the connection string in the first place. Any pointers for trying a different ADO.NET provider?

Comment: To answer the specific question in the title, the replacement for `app.config` in the dotnet core world is `appsettings.json`. At least in dotnet core 3.1 and earlier. Still the same in 5.0 I'm guessing?